# Django signals not executed

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem with Django signals, I don't know why but they are not executed.

I have created an "events" application with some views, everything works except the signals.

My model :

```py
class Events(models.Model):
    """
    Events
    """
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nom", max_length=50)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de début")
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de fin")
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name="Adresse", max_length=80)
    postal_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="code postal")
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="Ville",max_length=50)
    registered_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Personnes inscrites",
                                              related_name="event_registered_users",
                                              blank=True)
    max_users = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Nombre de personnes maximum")
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Réservé aux membres de l'association ?")
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryEvent, verbose_name="categorie", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "évènement"
        verbose_name_plural = "évènements"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My function linked to a signal:

```py
from .models import Events

@receiver(post_save, sender=Events)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Events)
def delete_cache_event_events(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Clear cache
    """
    print("clear")
    cache.delete(f"details_event_{instance.pk}")
    cache.delete(f"list_events_categories_{instance.category.pk}")
```

If I save a new event or update an existing one, the signal is not executed.
(the cache is not cleared and I can't see "clear" in the console).

Comment: Where do you *load* the signals? In the app config?

Comment: What do you mean?
I have added signals in the past, I don't remember having to modify the apps.py

Comment: you need to somehow load the `signals.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the signals, for example in the `AppConfig`. If your app uses as name `app_name` for example, you can make an `AppConfig` with:

```
# app_name/config.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppNameAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'

    def ready(self):
        import app_name.signals  # noqa
```

and then specify this as the main app config:

```
# app_name/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'app_name.config.AppNameAppConfig'
```

That being said, using signals is [often an antipattern [lincolnloop.com]](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). It makes code less predictable, and there are several ways to circumvent signals with the ORM.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But it doesn't work. I found the issue. I can't use delete_* in the name. I replace by remove_* and it's works

Comment: I guess OP's issue was an error in their code, but thanks a lot this worked for me. Thanks for being a life saver.